# How to know if my ElasticSearch is vulnerable against Log4j?

Tags: magento2, security, elasticsearch, docker

I don't have Java installed in my main Docker, but I'm using ElasticSearch v6.8.3 in another instance.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

[image: ElasticSearch 6 against Log4j]

Am I vulnerable against Log4j even not running ElasticSearch inside of the same instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ElasticSearch instance isn't publicly accessible or exposed, you're good. But you need to upgrade your ElasticSearch to the lasted version that fixes the Log4j vulnerability anyways.

ElasticSearch 6 -> [6.8.21](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-notes-6.8.21.html) to avoid the vulnerability.

ElasticSearch 7 -> [7.16.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/release-notes-7.16.1.html) to avoid the vulnerability.

I recommend running this command below to have an [extra verification](https://rafaelcg.com/blog/developer/magento-log4j/).

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/log4j_checker_beta/main/log4j_checker_beta.sh -q -O - |bash
```

Reference: [ElasticSearch Log4j – Magento 2](https://rafaelcg.com/blog/developer/avoid-log4j-elasticsearch/)